# Draggable - Droppable positioning bug?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm making an activity that requires certain letters to be put in certain places to complete words.

Here's a screenshot:

[The Activity I'm Working On](https://i113.photobucket.com/albums/n218/shared_bond/Untitled-1_zpseb7350af.jpg~original)
(linking it because it's too big)

The two small wooden boards at the bottom contain the letters that should be dragged to the blank boxes on the bigger wooden boards. The problem is that every time I try to drag the letters into the blank spaces, it does this:

[image]

And if I don't drag it to that certain spot (for example, I want to place it exactly at the center of the red box), it reverts to its original position as if I never dropped it in a droppable.

Is this a bug? Is there a workaround?

Here's the script:

```
    $(".drag").draggable({ revert: 'invalid' });

/*======================================================*/  

    $( "#dropArea1A" ).droppable({

                        accept: '.drag',
                        drop: function( event, ui) {
                            console.log(ui.draggable.attr('class'));
                            console.log(answers);
                            console.log(correct);

                            if(ui.draggable.hasClass('letterH')){ choice1 = 'correct'; $('#dropArea1A').addClass('correct') }

                            $(".drag").css('cursor', 'default');
                            $(".drag").append(ui.draggable.css('margin','0'));
                            $(".draggable").draggable({ disabled: false });
                            $(this).append(ui.draggable.css('position','static'));
                            $(this).droppable( 'disable' );

                        },

                    });
```

And some additional info that might be useful: I used `position: absolute` *a lot* in the stylesheet to get the droppable divs into the correct position. The wooden boards (and the static letter boxes) are background images. Would this be the culprit?

Comment: Do you have browser zoom enabled? this could interfere with it. Press `Ctrl` + `0` (zero) to reset the zoom and see if the problem still exists

Comment: @Thomas: Tried to make sure browser zoom wasn't enabled, but the zoom was still exactly at 100%...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some chat room traversing and playing around with jsfiddle, I found that droppable areas have problems with the css `margin` property, not `position: absolute`. What  happens is, if you set a `margin-top` or a `margin-left` or any other value for the `margin` property, *only the element will move* -- the *drop area will not*.

I hope this helps someone!

Answer (score 0):

This issue was reported four years ago here: http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/6876

It was recently fixed in jquery-ui 1.11.2